# Geth/Ropsten light node can't find suitable peers even after adding peers

Tags: go-ethereum, ropsten

I am trying to deploy a test contract on Ropsten test net. I have started a light node using the command:

```
geth --testnet --datadir=./.ropsten --syncmode=light --rpc --rpcapi="personal,eth,network,web3,net"--rpcaddr localhost --rpcport 8545
```

When I try to deploy my test contracts using truffle, I am getting the error "no suitable peers available". From what I understand from similar questions, I am aware that we are able to add peers from this gist: https://gist.github.com/rfikki. However, even after successfully adding the peers (all returning true) and the node is up-to-date, I am not able to deploy the contract or call functions like getBalance() due to the "no peers" error.

Does this mean that the peers in the gist are not running now, and I am not able to connect with any of those peers? Also, other than adding the peers, or adding bootnodes, is this the only solution for the "no suitable peers" error when running a light node?

Comment: I frequently experience this with light peers on the ropsten network. I might get a peer for a few days, but then I'm back to 0 again. The only solution I have found so far is to run a fast node, but that does require more resources (300GB storage space on an SSD).